# using dense_rank to find distinct

Tags: sql

I have a table something like this

```
Id  student_name    City
4   abc             Mumbai
6   xyz             Delhi
4   lmn             Kolkata
6   abc             Mumbai
6   GHI             Chennai
```

I am using `dense_rank()` function to dismiss the duplicate entry of `ID` in the table means if I am having the `ID` 4 twice it should give me only once in the output.

When I am using `dense_rank` function like:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by student_id desc  ) as ID ,Id, student_name,city
from test
```

It is giving me the output something like this

```
ID  ID  student_name    city
1   4   abc             Mumbai
1   4   lmn             kolkata
2   6   xyz             Delhi
2   6   abc             Mumbai
```

But I don't want duplicate how to remove using `dense_rank()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `dense_rank()` in the `select` does not do filtering.  So, I don't know why the output would have four rows when the input has five.

Second, to keep only one row per id, then use `row_number()`, not `dense_rank()` . . . along with a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by student_id order by student_id) as seqnum
      from test t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```